# Spring class not created on database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Hello everyone so I have a problem in spring boot, The class I've created doesn't seem to be created on the database after I run the project

Here's the application properties file

I don't know what value to put on server.port

```java
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8070/magasin?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
  server.port=8087
```

Here's my CLIENT class

```java
package tn.esprit.spring.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table( name = "Client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="idClient")
private Long idClient; 

@Column(name="nom")
private String nom;

@Column(name="prenom")
private String prenom;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="dateNaissance")
private Date dateNaissance;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="profession")
private Profession profession;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="categorieClient")
private CategorieClient categorieClient;

public Long getIdClient() {
    return idClient;
}
public void setIdClient(Long idClient) {
    this.idClient = idClient;
}
public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}
public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}
public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}
public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public Date getDateNaissance() {
    return dateNaissance;
}
public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
    this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
}
public Profession getProfession() {
    return profession;
}
public void setProfession(Profession profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}
public CategorieClient getCategorieClient() {
    return categorieClient;
}
public void setCategorieClient(CategorieClient categorieClient) {
    this.categorieClient = categorieClient;
}
}
```

Database I'm working on , I used port 8070 for XAMP
[image]

This is the output, can you guys help me find the error? It's preventing me from creating the table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

8070 is a port that phpmyadmin is exposed on. Mysql server port s dfferent. Try default MYSQL port 3306